# Create Markets Bubble Indicator

Tags: statistics, risk-management, risk-models, credit-risk

I am trying to replicate a Bubble Indicator described  [here](http://www.riskelia.com/blog/2014/08/the-predictable-high-yield-debt-meltdown%E2%80%A6/).

The indicator is strictly based on calculating the regularity of price behavior to determine herding in multiple time frames. I tried the Hurst exponent on series returns but could not replicate the results.

Data for the second chart EU High Yield can be found [here](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/BAMLHE00EHYITRIV/downloaddata)

Any potential ideas to replicate this?

Comment: I think you cannot replicate those results without a paper about how to construct this indicator; Moreover, Riskelia is a corporation and it is difficult that this kind of business reality says how to construct an indicator that after they have to sell :)

Comment: Did you find some reference about this indicator?